# How to change the style of a marker from a KML file?

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth

I am trying to change the style of a marker from a KML file in googlemaps. When I run the file in googleearth, the marker is different. When I run it in googlemaps it's just the same looking marker as before. Why is that happening?

Here's the beginning of the kml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.google.com/earth/kml/1">
<Document>

<Style id="bendigo">
<BalloonStyle>
    <text>$[description]</text>
</BalloonStyle>
<IconStyle>
    <Icon>
        <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-blank.png</href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
</Style>

<name>kml_sample1.kml</name>
<Placemark>
 <name>Boat</name>
 <description><![CDATA[
  Boat<br />
  <p>Home page: <a href="google.com">google.com</a></p>
 ]]>
 </description>

 <styleUrl>#bendigo</styleUrl>

<Point>
<!--run a javascript to get data points-->
  <coordinates>7.666037,64.32565</coordinates>
</Point>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your KML snippet above is missing ending tags for Placemark, Document, and kml.

Once fixed I was able to load the KML into Google Maps and it looks fine (green marker).

There was a recent update to the KML is rendered in Google Maps which may have temporarily affected this, but I am unable to be sure since it works fine for me now.  If you confirm it now looks fine to you, that was probably the issue.

Comment: huh, I don't get it (I know it's missing snippets it's just the essential part). But Now it works. It seems like there is a long lag between when I change a kml file to when I see the results. Do you know why this is the case and how to deal with it? oh well the code I wrote works now :-/

Comment: Your KML is cached on Google's servers.  However (and this was a recent addition some months ago) the caching should respect your cache headers -- with a minimum cache time of 5 minutes.  So you set your cache headers to at least 5 minutes, and if you need an immediate update for testing purposes only you can add a random url parameter to get an uncached copy (but please don't do this on your production site!)

Comment: do you have a reference so I can re-cache every 5 minutes?

Comment: You want Cache-Control "max-age=300".  How you set this depends on how you're serving the data (e.g. via IIS, apache, django, whatever).  But you should be able look it up pretty easily for your server.